# Designing a class diagram using n-ary association

Tags: database, uml, associations, class-diagram

I have a scenario involving three classes: Planner, Agent (a sales agent), and Client. Here's the scenario:

The Planner class has a list of clients, and the planner selects a client from the list and associates an agent with that client. The agent then visits the client to sell products. Additionally, a Sale Operation class needs to be created to store extra information about the sale, such as the products sold.

I'm currently stuck between two possible solutions for designing the class relationships. Here are the two solutions I have considered:

Solution 1:
In this solution, I have a direct association between Planner and Agent, and a direct association between Agent and Sale Operation. However, I don't have a direct association between Planner and Client, as I simply fetch a list of clients and then assign an agent to a selected client.
Here's the diagram for Solution 1:
[image]

The problem I encountered with Solution 1 is that it lacks a direct association between Planner and Client. The relationship is more indirect, as the Planner class only has a list of clients and assigns an agent to a selected client.

In this solution, I removed the association between Planner and Client, and instead, I added an association between Planner and Agent, considering that a Planner assigns an agent. However, this introduces a many-to-many relationship between Planner and Agent, requiring the addition of a third class.

Here's the diagram for Solution 2:

[image]

While Solution 2 establishes an association between Planner and Agent, it creates a many-to-many relationship between these classes, necessitating the introduction of a third class.

### Edit: Additional solution

Solution 3 :
[image]

after reading the comments and proposed solutions, i added this solution ( and removed the n-air association as its not UML )
class of sale isn't created until the planner assigns an agent , and every sale operation has a client in its attribute ( that the planner chose before assigning an agent )

I would appreciate guidance on selecting the most appropriate solution or any alternative suggestions that would best represent the relationships between Planner, Agent, Client, and Sale Operation, considering the scenario outlined above.

Comment: You should get rid of sll these `id` attributes. Looks likes you were designing a RDBMS.

Comment: You won't _design_ a CD except you want to make it some piece of art. Instead, you design a system - and _use_ a CD for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry if I was ambiguous: an n-ary association is ok in UML. It's just that multiplicities can only be on the ends and not on the side of the diamond.

Comment: Your "Solution 3" is not a solution. When you use an association class like "Sale", you cannot name the association (with "assign"). Your "Solution 3" is no better than "Solution 2". It also does not decouple the agent client assignment from sales or sales leads.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis of the initial solutions

Unfortunately, none of the solutions capture the semantics needed for your problem, as the time dimension was missed:

> The Planner <strike>class</strike> has a list of clients, and the planner selects a client from the list and associates an agent with that client.

This means that you may for example have a `Planner` instance, that at one moment in time has 10 `Client` in its list, but 5 of them have no Agent assigned yet (perhaps because your system's purpose it to help make these assignements?). This kills solution 2.

The diagram of solution 1 is by the way not UML compliant: in the n-ary association there should be a multiplicity only at the ends and not on the side of the diamond.

Let's suppose you got solution 1 diagramme right. In this case the client would be associated with a planner only if there's a sale,  because your n-ary association is an association class. This kills solution 1, because not all the assignments lead to a sale.

You need to reconsider the model, taking into account the time perspective.

### Edit: additional solution 3

The additional solution is similar to the n-ary one. It has the advantage of being clearer about multiplicities.

From the model semantics I understand that what you call "sale" is in fact a "sales lead" or a "sale opportunity" in sales terminology.

Still missing in the model is the fact that each planner has a list of clients. There is one solution which is using solution 3 and add the missing association.

Comment: you said "because not all the assignments lead to a sale" i know that but still a class of sale is created even if a sale didn't happen and its status would indicate that this sale operation failed , so it will be created anyway, does that make the solution 1 right in this case ?

Comment: @ItsYasser "a class of sale is created" is very confusing: is it about the class or the objects that belong to the class? In the second case , "a class of sale is instantiated" or" a Sale object is created" would be more accurate. Again from time perspective it seems a very bad idea to create a sale whereas the agent not even contacted the client.  Then what productSold would you put ?

Comment: Last but not least, in solution 1 you'd still not able to show that a client  is unassigned, because if there's a client and no other linked instance at all, there's no association. You'd need at least to members in an n-ary occurence. (Even if you could have such a non-association: in your approach you'd create an sale for every unassigned client. What will you do if the client then gets assigned: create a new sale ? delete the old sale ? update end date of old sale ? This is a lot of work for maintaining consistency and a lot of useless objects). So it's not a good solution.

Comment: i think you took the sale word too serious , i just meant when an agent is assigned to the client , the agent then goes to the client and tries to make a sale , if the sale didn't happen well then the status of this sales is failed and the list of products is simply empty

Comment: @ItsYasser you could call it otherwise, I would slightly modify my wording for the same conclusions. But in the end, it is your design, and your choice. Maybe the best is to try it. If it is for an RDBMS implementation, I'd not be surprise if you'll soon agree with me ;-)

Comment: mine is actually for a non relational database

Comment: @ItsYasser: It doesn't matter if your DB is relational or not. You always have table-like structures corresponding to classes.

Answer (score 0):

> The Planner class has a list of clients, and the planner selects a client from the list and associates an agent with that client. The agent then visits the client to sell products. Additionally, a Sale Operation class needs to be created to store extra information about the sale, such as the products sold.

Your narrative implies that there are six classes: Planner, Client, Agent, ClientVisit, Sale, Product.

You need to modify and extend your version 1 model by

1. detaching your `Sale` class from the ternary association and, instead, attach a `ClientVisit` class to it (however, this merges assignments with client visits, so if it's not important to record both client visits and sales, then better call the ternary association "Assignment");
2. Associate your `Sale` class with `Client` and `Agent` (and `Product`).

This changed model allows agents and clients that are not yet assigned, and it allows later sales for some of the assignments/visits.

Comment: i have edited my answer and proposed another appraoch , please tell me what you think 
concerning your solution, i dont need another class for the clientVisit because i want to have all that information inside the sale class simply by adding an attribute called status that would indicate if the sale happened or not

Comment: A sale that didn't happen is not a sale and therefore shouldn't be called a "Sale".

Comment: yes i just called it a sale to simplify my problem , to be precise its a mission to sale , so you can replace the sale class by mission class , and that mission could fail or succeed